# Extract malayalam text from PDF

Tags: c#-4.0

How to extract malayalam text from pdf . I tried using Itextcsharp with the following code, but giving wrong result

```
List<String> pdfText = new List<string>();  
for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++){

ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
String strPage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

strPage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default,
          Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strPage)));

pdfText.Add(strPage);
```

}

Comment: could you elaborate on the "wrong result"?

Comment: When I tested , I got result like 

1; SvlfjuksmigijsRyYeSfUdftï\#


2;dkfkdSalsmi'flgln\#


3;f{S]}uksmigi\tÍsrulujgk'k#


4;aohdXSflykAeo]xsaqkfji'flgln\#


5;eoglmAi'f\tÍsruln\#


6;fjgkSilnAi'f\tÍsruln\#


7;vjYfefAzAelyjigkSÝlX-gln\tÙjuf\#


8;QlnsÙ]kyjv3\eÙ\ildUsaqkfkd"%

Comment: Text extraction is working perfectly when pdf content is in English, if any other language is there then result is like the above characters

Comment: Hey Shan, Have you got any solution ? I am also facing the same issue. Please help.

Comment: @Shan.  If you can read the Malayalam text in pdf by eye, I think the malayalam font used in the PDF is not Unicode and hence we see ASCII characters. Check the font once. It will be better to post a snapshot of the text. I have seen text extraction in Tamil working to some degree, so this should also work if the font is Unicode. I may be able to reply if you give more details